# Как сделать запись в базе данных MySQL (При помощи mysqli ООП) с переменными (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, phpmyadmin

Есть 3 переменные `$title` `$content` `$image`, которые принимают данные из массивов `$_POST` и `$_FILES`. Мне нужно сделать запись в базу при помощи ООП варианта mysqli, при этом в качестве значений вставить значения переменных. Пробовал разные варианты mysql-запроса, записей в БД нет. Ошибок не выдаёт, но `$response` пустой.

```js
$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$image = $_FILES['image'];

function uploadImage($image) {
    $extension = pathinfo($image['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION); // "jpg"
    $filename = uniqid().".".$extension; // создаём уникальное полное название файла
    move_uploaded_file($image['tmp_name'], "../uploads/".$filename); // перемещаем файл в папку uploads
    return $filename; // возвращаем название файла
};

function createPost($title, $content, $filename) {
// PDO

// MySQLi ООП
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "dragon_blog");
    if ($connect->connect_errno) {
        echo "Не удалось подключиться к базе данных MySQL. Ошибка: ".$connect->connect_errno.'<br>'.'Описание ошибки: '.$connect->connect_error;
    };

    $response = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `content`, `image`) VALUES (`$title`, `$content`, `$filename`)");

    if (!$response) {
        echo "Не удалось выполнить запрос: (" . $connect->connect_errno . ") " . $connect->connect_error;
    }
    $connect->close();
};

$uploadFile = uploadImage($image);
createPost($title, $content, $uploadFile);
```

Comment: для ошибок запроса  $connect->error надо смотреть

Comment: А еще надо понимать в чем разница между кавычками `'` и бэктиками `\``.

Comment: Пробовал и с кавычками, и с бэктиками, не работает никак) Но ошибки теперь отдаёт.

Answer (score 0):

```
$response = $connect->query("INSERT INTO `posts` (`title`, `content`, `image`) VALUES ('{$title}', '{$content}', '{$filename}')");
```

Бектики подходят только для экранирования имен (полей,таблиц,баз банных), но строковые значения нужно окружать двойными (") или одинарными (') кавычками. К тому же, если вы используете sql-инъекции в запросах (да-да, это именно инъекции), то вам так же нужно позаботится об экранировании этих кавычек в строковых значениях.

Либо (что я лично рекомендую), используйте [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)

Так же, ваш код:

```
if (!$response) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить запрос: (" . $connect->connect_errno . ") " . $connect->connect_error;
}
```

Отображает ошибки **подключения**, а не запроса.

Правильно будет так:

```
if (!$response) {
    echo "Не удалось выполнить запрос: (" . $connect->errno . ") " . $connect->error;
}
```